# android studio layout textbox not show on mobile app when running

Tags: android-studio

I am developing a mobile app in Android Studio, using page layout.

I have created a profile page, it contains an image and two buttons. So my doubt is if I add a textbox above the image, it is successfully created, but when I run my app the textbox is not visible.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Could you add the xml for the page? You can edit it into your post using the "edit" link below your question.

Comment: i am find the solution ......thanks for your response.....

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it! You could add your solution as an answer; it may help future visitors.

Comment: add new textbox(i.e.editText) to mobile layout(layout-sw320dp) in android studio and run my application that problem could be solved...